# If $F$ is entire with removable singularity at $\infty$, then $F$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

On page 24 of Krantz's [Complex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=g-bLsOB-vegC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=entire+function+has+a+pole+at+infinity+then+it+is+a+polynomial&source=bl&ots=vsYB2jqqtf&sig=7dudrx-WvL0LfiFqPz1vbdhXthU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OvSlT-esLYTeiAKJydjSAg&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=entire%20function%20has%20a%20pole%20at%20infinity%20then%20it%20is%20a%20polynomial&f=false), there is the following proof:

> Proposition 2: If $F$ is entire and $F$ has a removable singularity at $\infty$, then $F$ is  constant.
>
> Proof: By examining $F(1/z)$, we see that $F$ must have a finite limit at $\infty$. Thus $F$ is bounded. By Liouville's theorem, $F$ is constant.

It's mysterious to me what is meant by the first sentence. What does he mean by "examining $F(1/z)$"? I tried expanding $F$ has a Laurent series around $0$, and then using the fact that $F(1/z)$ has the origin as a removable singularity, but I didn't get the conclusion.

Is the idea to do this?

Let 
$$
F(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
$$
be the Laurent expansion around the origin. Then
$$
F(1/z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^{-n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{-n}
$$
but since $F(1/z)$ has a removable singularity at the origin, we really have
$$
F(1/z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^{-n}+a_0.
$$
So $a_n=0$ for $n>0$, and thus $F(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}a_nz^n+a_0$, so $\lim_{z\to\infty}F(z)=a_0<\infty$?

Comment: Note you are essentially considering the transition map between coordinate patches on the Riemann sphere.

Answer (score 6):

Your idea is definitely going in the right direction.  You've found that $F(z)$ has a finite limit as $|z| \to \infty$, so you can find constants $M$ and $r$ such that $|F(z)| \leq M$ for all $|z| > r$.  Now, since $F$ is entire, what can you say about $|F(z)|$ for $|z| \leq r$?  Can you conclude that $|F(z)|$ is bounded for all $z$?

Comment: Does that just follow from the fact that $|z|\leq r$ is compact, and so $|F(z)|$ achieves a maximum on the disk? Since it's also bounded outside the disk, it must be bounded on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yup, that's it!

Comment: Thanks for confirming Antonio.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach via Laurent expansion:

Say we have the Taylor expansion around zero: $F(w)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nw^n$, then if $w=1/z$ for $z\neq 0$, and by uniqueness of the Laurent expansion we have that this is exactly the Laurent series. Now, a removable singularity at infinity of $F(z)$ means a removable singularity for $F(1/z)$ at $z=0$, but this can only happen if $a_n=0$ for $n>0$.